# What is the syntax for defining a type when parameter has a default value?

Tags: flowtype

How do I define the type of the `config` parameter given that it has a default value?

```js
function (config = {}) {};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`function f(config: Object = {}) {}`

Or, more generally:

`function f(p: T = v) {}`

where `T` is a type, and `v` is a value of type `T`.

Interestingly, the type of function `f` is `(p?: T): void`. That is, Flow understands that providing a default value makes the parameter optional. You don't need to explicitly make the parameter type optional—although it doesn't hurt.

When writing `declare function` statement in a `.js.flow` file, you can't include the default value; it will cause an error.  So you must explicitly declare that the parameter is optional:

`declare function f(p?: T): void;`

Answer (score 0):

Flow types and default arguments in fat-arrow functions work similarly.

Given a function called `foo` which takes argument `bar`, you specify the type immediately after the argument with a colon, and then set its default value with the assignment (=) operator.  Finally, immediately after closing the parentheses, you define the return value's type with another colon.

```
foo = (bar: string = 'baz'): string => bar;
foo(); // 'baz'
```