# type annotation for parameter with default value

Tags: flowtype

In the following function definition:

```
 function foo(a: number = 42): number {return a+1;}
```

… what are the semantics of the `a: number` annotation?

Is it saying that variable *a* will always have a value inside
the body of the function or is it saying that client programmers should always supply a value when they make the call?

I've noticed that both the below code snippets type-check with no errors (with flow-bin 0.57.3):

### snippet 1

```
function foo(a: number = 42): number {return a+1;}
type FooT= (a: number)=> number

(foo: FooT)

foo();
```

(try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYUccAFAIYBcYWGAtgEYCmATmALxgAsATAEo6DFhzABvdqzwZ2JKgGoAjAG4AvqjwBPAA6swAMXIAVHtRFM27QVwB89Kx1SoKZOHWNwTgl+4qCqkA))

### snippet 2

```
function foo(a: ?number = 42): number {return a+1;}
type FooT = (a: ?number)=> number

(foo: FooT)

foo();
```

(try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYUccAFAIYBcYA-FhgLYBGApgE5gC8YALACYAlHSZsuYAN6d2eDJxJUA1AEYA3AF9UeAJ4AHdmABi5ACq8w1OoxYdOwngD4w4+6lQUycOqbhnhD28KYXUgA))

What is the suggested way to annotate in such a case?

My preference is with way #2 as the client programmer only has to look at the definition of the `FooT` type to realize that the parameter is optional. This allows me to tell users of my 
library: "simply look at the type of the function (`FooT`)".

Whereas with way #1 I have to tell them "the type of the function (`FooT`) seems to suggest that an argument is required, but in fact it isn't because, see, if you look at the implementation, a default value is supplied".

So, which snippet is more idiomatic?

Note that there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33097444/274677) to a related question that seems to suggest that it is possible to annotate the type as mandatory in the implementation of a function and as optional in the declaration. But this doesn't seem to work in this case. E.g. the following doesn't type-check:

```
function foo(a: number = 42): number {return a+1;}
type FooT = (a: ?number)=> number

(foo: FooT)

foo();
```

(try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYUccAFAIYBcYWGAtgEYCmATmALxgAsATAEo6DFhzABvdqzwZ2JKgGoAjAG4AvqjwBPAA6swAMXIAVbmGp0A-KLbtBXAHz0md1Kgpk4dY3BOD3LwpBVSA))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go with:

```
function foo(a: number = 42): number {return a+1;}
type FooT = (a?: number)=> number

(foo: FooT)

foo();
```

Pay attention to `?` position in type definition:

`(a?: number)` - [optional](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-optional-function-parameters) parameter

vs

`(a: ?number)` - [maybe](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types) type

The only difference between the two is that the optional parameter **can't be null**, just like a [parameter with default value](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-function-parameters-with-defaults)